# How to handle an Exceptions in a Stream in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream, rxdart

I'm subscribing to a collection in firestore and I would like to handle errors firestore can throw in the `snapshots` stream. The errors should be catched and emit a `left(UnexpectedFailure)` in the stream and shouldn't terminate the stream. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code sample:

```
@override
  Stream<Either<Failure, List<Foo>>> getStream() {
    String uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid;
    return firestore
        .collection(FOO_COLLECTION)
        .doc(uid)
        .collection(FOO_COLLECTION)
        .snapshots()
        .map(
      (querySnapshot) {
        try {
          return right<Failure, List<Foo>>(querySnapshot.docs
              .map((doc) => FooDto.fromFirestore(doc).toDomain())
              .toList());
        } catch (e) {
          return left(UnexpectedFailure(e));
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Any answers/comments are highly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful - [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/errors). You need to add `on FirebaseAuthException` to your catch statement.